# Proving two sets $A, B$ are order isomorphic

Tags: proof-writing, order-theory, well-orders

Let $A, B$ be well ordered sets. If $A$ is order isomorphic to a subset of $B$, and $B$ is order isomorphic to a subset of $A$, prove that $A, B$ are order isomorphic.

I know that two well ordered set is order isomorphic iff there exists a increasing function(i.e. $x<_A y \Rightarrow f(x)<_B f(y)$) from $A$ to $B$ which is bijective. The first thing I thought was the well ordering isomorphic theorem(if $(A, \le_A), (B, \le_B )$ are well orderd, only one of $A \cong B, A \cong B[b] \ \exists!b \in B, \ A[a] \cong B \ \exists!a \in A$) must hold, and the isomorphism is unique.)

Where do I have to start the proof?

Comment: This is known as the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem, or a variant of it. The traditional proof uses the well-ordering principle (aka the axiom of choice), but as you are given two well-ordered sets, this can be done constructively.

Comment: @JamesLeslie May I see the traditional proof of the theorem? I tried to search it, but failed to do so. I don't quite understand the sketch of Brian M. Scott, so I might have to watch yours.

Comment: @JamesLeslie: This is **not** the Cantor-Schröder-Berstein theorem and does not follow from it, and the C-S-B theorem does not require the axiom of choice. The C-S-B theorem merely says that if there are injections from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$, then there is a bijection between them; it says nothing about whether these maps respect any order structure that may be present on $A$ and $B$. This result is much easier to prove than the C-S-B theorem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This question is the same as asking whether the category of well ordered sets satisfies the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein property, so I think it's fair to say that the statement at hand is a variant of it. What I said does give the wrong impression though, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @JamesLeslie: It is similar in structure, but in terms of proof there is no useful relationship between them, so it is not at all useful here to call one a variant of the other, and I would go so far as to say that it is actually misleading in the context of the OP’s question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKETCH: Let $B'$ be a subset of $A$ order-isomorphic to $B$. Recursively construct an order-isomorphism from $B'$ onto an initial segment, not necessarily proper, of $A$. If this order-isomorphism is onto $A$, compose it with the order-isomorphism from $B$ into $A$ to get the desired order-isomorphism from $B$ onto $A$. If not, get a contradiction by using the order-isomorphism of $A$ to a subset of $B$ to get an order-isomorphism of $A$ into a proper initial segment of itself, from which you can recursively construct an order-isomorphism of $A$ onto a proper initial segment of itself.

Comment: What do you mean by 'recursively construct an order-isomorphism'?

Comment: @John.P: Let me ask first: how did you prove the well-ordering isomorphism theorem?

Comment: @John.P: I ask in order to get a better idea of what background you have.

Comment: I thought it was rather complicated. I am not quite sure I understood it perfectly, but I understood the flow of the proof.
Let $C:= \{ x \in A| \exists r \in B s.t. A[x] \cong B[r] \}$, and since for $x \in C, \exists ! r \in B$, so I construct a function from C to B. Then, let D be the range of F, and prove C and D are order isomorphic

Comment: @John.P: Unfortunately, that doesn’t tell me much. I asked specifically because it probably used a recursive construction of an order-isomorphism, precisely the tool that I’d use here. If you’re constructing an order-isomorphism $\varphi$ from $B'$ to an initial segment of $A$, you let $\varphi(\min B')=\min A$, and when you’ve defined $\varphi(x)$ for each $x\in B'$ less than some $b$, you define $\varphi(b)$ to be the least member of $A$ that is not $\varphi(x)$ for some $x\in B'$ less than $b$.

Comment: Then I prove $C=A \lor C = A[x], D = B \lor D = B[y]$, but not $C=A[x] \land D=B[y]$. This was quite complicated,but by this I could prove well-ordering isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @John.P: Ah, okay. That function from $C$ to $B$ is similar to what you need here.

Comment: I have written a proof of mine, thanks to your help, and added to my question. Could you read it and tell me whether it is right or wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107637/discussion-between-john-p-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @John.P: (I was away for a while.) Your addition is a little wordy and a little more involved than is absolutely necessary, but it appears to be okay, and you’ve reached the expected contradiction, that $A$ is order-isomorphic to a proper initial segment of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Without recursion.

Let $<$ be a well-order on $A.$ A proper initial segment ($pis$) of $A$ is $pred_<(a)=\{a'\in A:a'<a\}$ for some (any) $a\in A.$ ("pred" for "predecessors"). I will define $a^*=\{a\}\cup pred_<(a).$

Claim: There is no order-isomorphism of $A$ to any subset of any $pis$ of $A.$

Proof. By contradiction, suppose $a\in A$ and $f:A\to C$ is an order-isomorphism with $C\subset pred_<(a).$ Then $f$ maps $a^*$ order-isomorphically to a subset of $pred_<(a).$

So consider $a_0,$ the $<$-least $a\in A$ such that there is an order-isomorphism of $a^*$ to a subset of $pred_<(a),$ and let $f_0$ be  an order-isomorphism from  $a_0^*$ to a subset of $pred_<(a_0).$

By the minimality of $a_0,$ if $b<a_0$ then $\{f_0(c):c\in b^*\}$ cannot be a subset of $pred_<(b)$ so $\exists c\le b\,(b\le f_0(c)).$ But $c\le b<a_0$ implies $f_0(c)\le f_0(b) .$

So for any $b<a_0$ we have $b\le f_0(b).$

BUT now in the case $b=f_0(a)$ we have $[\,a_0>b\land f(a_0)=b\le f(b)\,],$ so $f$ is not an order-isomorphism, a contradiction.

I think the rest of the Q has been fully addressed in other Answer(s) and Comments.

Comment: The proof of the claim is just an adaptation of the proof for the special  case $C=pred_<(a).$